# submitting a div element with form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using a form_for tag to submit a few text field a user enters, however in the same page, index.html.erb a timer is being run through assets>js>controller_name.js.coffee which is updating the a '.Timer' div class with a very simple counter; I want to submit the form eateries as well as the .text from the div on submit, how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the div content

```
$('#divID').html();
```

and then submit the form using jquery/javascript.

Thanks

Comment: at the moment im submitting using form_for helper provided by ruby, would I need to skip this and submit all enteries via a manual js function?